# Rectangular/Right hyperbolas through three points

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

> Find all equations of regular hyperbolas passing through the points $A(\alpha,0),B(\beta,0),$ and $C(0,\gamma)$.

**Attempt:** I am assuming here that regular means right. We can then write the equation of such as $(x-x_0)^2-(y-y_0)^2 =a^2$. Thus by the given we have $(\alpha-x_0)^2 -y_0^2 = a^2, (\beta-x_0)^2 -y_0^2 = a^2,$ and $x_0^2 - (\gamma-y_0)^2 = a^2.$ Therefore $\alpha-x_0 = \pm(\beta-x_0) \implies \alpha = \beta$ or $\alpha - 2x_0 = -\beta$.

I am not sure what to do next because we have a lot of variables and should I break this up into cases then with $x = \beta$ or $\alpha -2x_0 = -\beta$?

Comment: Removed `hyperbolic-geometry` tag, since the question is not about non-Euclidean space.

Comment: You're assuming not only are you assuming that "regular" means "right", but also that the hyperbola's transverse axis is parallel to the $x$-axis; to cover $90^\circ$ rotations of these, you simply replace your $a^2$ parameter with an un-squared $a$ that you allow to be negative. (Rotated hyperbolas complicate matters considerably.) Note that you've derived the relation $x_0 = \frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\beta)$; if you think about it, this is "obvious": points $A$ and $B$ (if distinct) must be symmetrically arranged about an axis of the hyperbola.

Comment: I *suspect* that the task intends $A$ and $B$ to be *distinct* points, in order that you get three equations in three unknowns ($x_0$, $y_0$, $a$). Allowing $\alpha=\beta$ will create a "one-parameter" family of solutions; and, if you're supposed to consider those, then you're probably also supposed to consider $\alpha = \beta = \gamma =0$: the two-parameter family of all regular hyperbola that pass through the origin.

Comment: Possibly OP was in a hurry and read "rectangular" as "regular".  "Rectangular", "equilateral", "right" all seem to be terms referring to hyperbolae with othogonal asymptotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conic section is characterized by five real degrees of freedom. Knowing three distinct points on it will account for three degrees of freedom (not six since each point might still move along the conic without changing it). Assuming that it's a right hyperbola should account for another degree of freedom, so we should end up with a one-parameter family of conics. But how to find them?

One useful tool is [projective geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry), where you can use an [homogeneous coordinate vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) like $[x:y:0]$ to describe a point at infinity. This is also the direction of the asymptotes, since the asymptotes are just tangents at these points at infinity. If $[x_1:y_1:0]$ describes one tangent direction, $[y_1:-x_1:0]$ is the perpendicular one. So together with the given three points, that's five points defining a conic section. You just have to compute its equation.

This $x_1$ and $y_1$ may look like two parameters, but since these are homogeneous coordinates, the only thing that matters is their ratio. You could for example write $x_1=\cos(t),y_1=\sin(t)$ and characterize things in terms of an angle $t$. Adding a multiple of $90°$ to that angle would result in the same conic, since it would be defined by the same set of points. So you could also w.l.o.g. take $y_1=1$ and $x_1\in[-1,1)$ to obtain a unique description of each hyperbola.

I'm using [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) to work out the formula since I'm lazy:

```
PR.<x1,y1,alpha,beta,gamma> = QQ[]
A = vector((alpha, 0, 1))
B = vector((beta, 0, 1))
C = vector((0, gamma, 1))
D = vector((x1, y1, 0))
E = vector((y1, -x1, 0))
M1 = A.cross_product(B).column()*C.cross_product(D).row()
M2 = A.cross_product(C).column()*B.cross_product(D).row()
M = (E*M1*E)*M2 - (E*M2*E)*M1
M += M.transpose()
M = M.parent()(M/gcd(M.list()))
M
```

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 x_{1} y_{1} \gamma &
- x_{1}^{2} \gamma + y_{1}^{2} \gamma &
- x_{1} y_{1} \alpha \gamma -  x_{1} y_{1} \beta \gamma \\
- x_{1}^{2} \gamma + y_{1}^{2} \gamma &
-2 x_{1} y_{1} \gamma &
- x_{1} y_{1} \alpha \beta + x_{1} y_{1} \gamma^{2} \\
- x_{1} y_{1} \alpha \gamma -  x_{1} y_{1} \beta \gamma &
- x_{1} y_{1} \alpha \beta + x_{1} y_{1} \gamma^{2} &
2 x_{1} y_{1} \alpha \beta \gamma
\end{pmatrix}$$

If you wanted to, you could turn this [matrix representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections) into a polynomial equation, and also plug in $y_1=1$ as discussed above:

$$x_1\gamma\,(x^2-y^2)
-(x_1^2-1)\gamma\,xy
-x_1(\alpha+\beta)\gamma\,x
-x_1(\alpha\beta-\gamma^2)\,y
+x_1\alpha\beta\gamma = 0
\quad\text{with }x_1\in[-1,1)
$$

> I am assuming here that regular means right.

So am I. [Googling for “regular hyperbola”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22regular%20hyperbola%22) I found [one match](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:I42nbQQapF4J:formulas.tutorvista.com/math/hyperbola-formula.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=de) which claims

> For a regular hyperbola the eccentricity is $\sqrt{2}$.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_%28mathematics%29#Hyperbolas), that's just the eccentricity of a rectangular i.e. right hyperbola. So I think your interpretation of the term is likely correct.

Answer (score 1):

We'll assume, as discussed elsewhere, that the conic in question is a rectangular hyperbola (also referred to in the OP as a right hyperbola).

Suppose a conic passes through the points $A(a,0),B(b,0),C(0,c),D(0,d)$.

Reducing the equation by making $y=0$ or $x=0$, we deduce (see [Salmon, *Conic Sections*, pg 153, Ex 1](https://archive.org/details/atreatiseonconi09salmgoog/page/n172/mode/2up?view=theater) for details) that the equation is

$$
c d x^2+2hxy+ab y^2
-c d(a+b)x
-ab(c+d)y
+a b c d
=0,
$$
where $h$ is undetermined.

It's a well known result (see [Hatton, *Projective Geometry*, pg 243](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n249/mode/2up?q=rectangular&view=theater)) that if a rectangular hyperbola passes through the vertices of a triangle it also passes through the orthocentre.  It's also easy to see that the orthocenter of $\triangle{ABC}$ is on the $y$-axis, and this determines the $d$ in $D(0,d)$.

By varying $h$ we can run through the family of rectangular hyperbolae passing through $A,B,C$.

For the equation of a rectangular hyperbola, if the coefficient of $x^2$ is $a$, the coefficient of $y^2$ is $-a$.  So
$$
ab=-cd \implies d=-\frac{ab}{c},
$$
sparing us the trouble of calculating the orthocenter of $\triangle{ABC}$.

Answer (score -1):

Use the equation $$ A x^2 + B y^2 + D x + E  y = 1 $$

With the points given you have three equations

$$ \begin{align} A \alpha^2 + D \alpha & = 1 \\ A \beta^2 + D \beta & = 1 \\
B \gamma^2 + E \gamma 7 & = 1 \end{align} $$

I include a skew parameter $\zeta = -B/A$ also to parametrize all the curves and together I get the solution

$$\begin{align} 
  A & = -\frac{1}{\alpha \beta} \\ 
  B & = \frac{\zeta}{\alpha \beta} \\
  D & = \frac{\alpha+\beta}{\alpha \beta} \\
  E & = \frac{\alpha \beta - \zeta \gamma^2}{\alpha \beta \gamma}
\end{align} $$

These coefficients give all the curves passing through the points, for every $\zeta \neq 0$.

Note that when $\zeta<0$ the result is an ellipse with a circle at $\zeta =- 1$.

Comment: You are ignoring the condition to get a *right* hyperbola, and you are also ignoring rotated hyperbolas since your initial equation doesn't contain a $xy$ term. And last but not least, assuming a right hand side of 1 will be problematic if the origin were to lie on the conic, which in this case can only happen if the hyperbola degenerates to a pair of lines, namely the coordinate axes.

Comment: I thought a right hyperbola is one without a $ x y $ term with its major/minor axes being the x and y axes. To include an $x y$ coefficient will yield two independent parameter that the family of curves is going to depends on. Also I decided on the $\ldots =1$ instead of the standard homogeneous coordinates $\ldots +F = 0$ in order to have only 4 dependent quantities. Plus the _OP_ did not  include any of the stuff you mention.